# Spring Boot Thymeleaf download file after successful login

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to provide a webservice with spring boot, which is able to download a dump from a MySQL database.

But the download shouldn´t be able for everybody. So I need a kind of login. It´s not quite sure where the credentials will be stored, there is the possibility, that they´re just hard coded in the application itself.

I´m kind of lost and don´t know how to implement it.

Here is what i got so far:

```
@Controller
public class EBMysqldumpController {

    private EBMysqldumpService mysqldumpService;

    @Autowired
    public EBMysqldumpController(EBMysqldumpService mysqldumpService) {
        this.mysqldumpService = mysqldumpService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showLoginForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userDto", new UserDto());
        return "mysqldump-login";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/login")
    public String validateLoginForm(@Valid UserDto userDto, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "mysqldump-login";
        }

        if (!this.mysqldumpService.checkLogin(userDto)) {
            result.addError(new ObjectError("", "Wrong username and/or password"));
            return "mysqldump-login";
        }

        return "redirect:/file";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/file")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> startMysqlDump(@Valid UserDto userDto, Model model) throws IOException, InterruptedException, MysqldumpException {
        if (!this.mysqldumpService.checkLogin(userDto)) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        File mysqlDump = this.mysqldumpService.getMysqlDumpFile();
        ByteArrayResource byteArrayResource = this.mysqldumpService.getByteArrayResourceFromFile(mysqlDump);

        HttpHeaders headers = getMysqldumpHeaders(mysqlDump.getName());
        ResponseEntity<Resource> body = ResponseEntity.ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentLength(mysqlDump.length())
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .body(byteArrayResource);

        this.mysqldumpService.deleteFile(mysqlDump);

        return body;
    }

    private HttpHeaders getMysqldumpHeaders(String filename) {
        ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.inline().filename(filename).build();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentDisposition(contentDisposition);

        return headers;
    }

}
```

For now the controller shows a login page at "/login". After a form is submitted, the controller checks if the credentials are correct, if not it shows again the login page with the error messages.

But my problem is that I don´t what to do after the login was successful. The download is working when I call it directly, but with redirect it´s not working, because I made a post request to make sure just logged in user can download the file. If I make a get request, everybody can use the link.

I have the feeling, I´m handling the problem wrong. What would you recommend? How could I start the download, after the login was successful?

Comment: What do you want the app to do, functionally speaking? You want the user to receive a database dump file? Should they receive it upon login? Or after they click something?

Comment: @Woodchuck yes, I want the user to receive a database dump file. The user should receive it after he clicked the login button. I just need to identify the user to allow the dump.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add Spring Security to your project and have a single hardcoded user in there:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
            .withUser("user1").password("my-secret-pwd").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(
                    registry -> registry.mvcMatchers("/**").authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```